# Can't deduce template types?

Tags: d

So I have the following code:

```
void invert(T)(T[2][] arr)
{
    auto result = new T[2][arr.length];
    foreach (i, v; arr)
        result[i] = [-v[0], -v[1]];
    return result;
}
```

and I call it:

```
invert([[5, 6], [6, 7]]);
```

and I get:

> `test.d(94):` Error: template `test.invert(T)` does not match any function template declaration
>   `test.d(94):` Error: template `test.invert(T)` cannot deduce template function from argument types `!()(int[][])`

What's the easiest way to fix this without losing the auto-inference feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you can't have a literal which is a static array. You end up with a dynamic array - `int[][]` in this case - instead of the `int[2][]` that you want. The inference works just fine. It's the type that you're giving it which is wrong. You're going to have to create a variable of the correct type.

Comment: You can't cast a dynamic array to a static array. I think the compiler used to be silent about these things, but it disallows this now. This is a good thing since the two types are different (e.g. the `by value` versus `by reference` parameter passing).

Comment: Well, removing that possibility shortens my answer quite a bit.

Comment: So are you saying it's impossible to make a static array literal?